# Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to '/collection/update'

Tags: meteor

Meteor throws following exception on the server when I try to do an update on a collection.

```
Exception while invoking method '/reports/update' Error: 
    Did not check() all arguments during call to '/reports/update'
```

The call is simple enough:

```
Reports.update({ _id : this._id },{ $set : query });
```

Update:

I tried to add the ´check´ before the update

two versions were tried with the same result: the exception is still thrown
version 1

```
check(query, Match.Any);
```

version 2

```
var update = { $set : query };
check(update, Match.Any);
```

And the collection has the allow methods defined to allow anything:

```
  Reports.allow({
     insert: function(){
        return true;
     },
     update: function(){
        return true;
     },
     remove: function(){
        return true;
     }
  })
```

Where can I put the `check(query, Match.Any)` ?

Comment: when are you calling the update for the collection? is it from within meteor.method? or a some sort of event?

Comment: The update is called from an event. I know where to put the check in a Meteor.method but not in an event

Answer (score 0):

It is spouse to be the same either from an event or a meteor method.
here is an example:

```
Template.YourTemplateName.events({
"click #yourElement:function(event,template){
check(query,Match.Any);
 console.log("working");
 //will always log "working" 
}
});

"click #yourElement:function(event,template){
check("String",Number);
 console.log("Not working");
 //will throw an error and will not execute the log 
}
});
```

also you can try Match.test which will return true if the value matches a pattern.
example:

```
   "click #yourElement:function(event,template){
        if(Match.test("String",String)){
         console.log("working");
         //will execute  
        }
       }
     });
```